# How to use Sytem.Math.Round(double, int) in c# (chtml)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.OrgTable.Rows)
    {
       @foreach (var p in (List<MvcProject.Models.orgModel>)ViewBag.params)
        { 

          decimal temp = Math.Round(item[p.Abbreviation], (int)p.Count);
          @(temp)

         }
    }
```

Using the above line of code gave me the error below -

**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Math.Round(double, int)' has some invalid arguments**

In the above, Abbreviation is a string and Count is a decimal. I am not sure what is wrong with the above System.Math.Round(double,int) usage

Comment: What type of `Dictionary<,>` is `item`?

Comment: item is {System.Data.DataRow}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `item` is a `DataRow`, then the following should work:

```
Math.Round((double)item[p.Abbreviation], (int)p.Count);
```

Comment: It says - Cannot Implicity convert type 'double' to 'decimal'

Comment: OK, try `Math.Round((decimal)item[p.Abbreviation], (int)p.Count);` I'm assuming here that your DataRow has column-names that are found in p.Abbreviation, and that the data stored in those colunms is of type Decimal.

Comment: Excellent, Kent! You are right. It has column-names and data (decimal) is stored in those columns. But trying what you mentioned gave me - "Cannot convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'decimal'"

Comment: If you have some null values in the column, then you'll need to check for these. e.g. something like `object o = item[p.Abbreviation]; if (o != DBNull.Value) { decimal temp = (decimal)o; ... }`

Comment: I wish I could add more than +1

Answer (score 2):

Try `double.Parse(abbreviation)`. It needs to be explicitly converted to double.

Answer (score 2):

> Abbreviation is a string and Count is a decimal. I am not sure what is
>   wrong with the above System.Math.Round(double,int) usage

You've just answered your own question. The method expects a double and an int, and you're trying to hand it a string and a decimal. You're going to have to convert those types, for example by calling double.Parse(p.Abbreviation) to convert the string to a double.

Comment: I tried that, it gave me an error - Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: That means the string doesn't make sense as a double - you have bad data. For example, trying to call double.Parse("three") isn't going to magically give you a double, it's going to cause the exception you mentioned. If you need more help, we'd really need to know what your data looks like (I'm very suspicious about how a property called "abbreviation" could possibly contain anything like a double unless the property is *very* badly named).

Comment: p.Abbreviation has data something like - "NH", "SC" etc

Comment: Yeah, bad data - I think you're misunderstanding something here. Math.Round is supposed to round a number to a specified number of fractional digits. For example, you hand it the double 5.67 and the int 1 and it returns a rounded double of 5.7 (5.67 rounded to 1 fractional digit). There's no string involved anywhere. What are you actually trying to do? What you've described so far has nothing to do with rounding numbers.

Comment: Ah, wait, I think I misread something somewhere. You don't want Math.Round(p.Abbreviation), you want Math.Round(item[p.Abbreviation])